# Looping through csv file after user input to extract information

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, for-loop

I am extract the information from the csv file that the user inputs. For example if the user types in Nevada it will go through the csv file and pull the information from that row and print it to the user. But the result i keep getting is the last row in the csv file.

```
def create_csv(name):
    with open('details.csv', 'rt') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if row[1] == name:
                print(name)
        return print(row)
 page = requests.get("https://ix.cnn.io/data/novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov/us/states.json")

    js_resp = json.loads(page.text)

    states = []
    case = []
    deaths = []

    for item in js_resp['data']:
        states.append(item['name'])
        case.append(item['cases'])
        deaths.append(item['deaths'])

    details = pd.DataFrame(
        {'State': states,
         'Cases': case,
         'Death': deaths,
         }
    )

    details.to_csv('details.csv') 
 select = int(input('Please enter how you would like to look up information '
                           '"Press 1 for State, 2 for City, 3 for Zip" '))
 if select == 1:
            # Get input of which state the user want to look up
   s = input('Which state would you like to see ')
   break
```

Comment: `return print(row)` will just print the last row of the file and return None.

Comment: So I should just return( name) @Susmit Agrawal